# grant/revoke permission with adb

Tags: android, permissions

The Android documentation contains the following description of the adb grant and adb revoke commands.

> Use the adb tool to manage permissions from the command line: List
>   permissions and status by group: `$ adb shell pm list permissions -d -g`
>   Grant or revoke one or more permissions: `$ adb shell pm [grant|revoke]
>   <permission-name> ...`Analyze your app for services that use
>   permissions.

i run this command, without any error message:

```
abd shell pm [grant|revoke] com.my.app android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
```

If i open settings -> apps -> myapp -> Permissions.
i dont see any changes...

How i know if my adb command works? Why there is no any change in the settings of app?

Comment: check this: https://greenify.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/749142-how-to-grant-permissions-required-by-some-features

Answer (score 7):

You're executing the following:

```
abd shell pm [grant|revoke] com.my.app android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
```

It should be **adb**, for *Android Debug Bridge*. i.e.

```
adb shell pm [grant|revoke] com.my.app android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
```