# Android: Grant permissions through ADB

Tags: android, permissions

For my application for some functionalities, I need to use the camera, which is not required to the core functionality of the application, so I need to specify the it's optional to use camera. So in the manifest I declared the permission as follows:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false"/>
```

But when I try to grant permission through adb using the following command it gives an error:

```
pm grant my.app.package android.permission.CAMERA
```

gives the error:

```
Operation not allowed: java.lang.SecurityException: Can't change android.permission.CAMERA. It is required by the application
```

My device is a rooted one and it runs android 5.1.1(22). According to the ADB [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html#pm), since the permission is declared as optional, I should be able to grant permission from adb as mentioned above. I have referenced [this](http://www.londatiga.net/it/programming/android/solution-to-make-an-android-app-visible-to-all-devices-in-google-play-when-using-specific-feature-2/), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9299993/optional-permissions-so-an-app-can-show-on-all-devices-and-enable-optional-featu) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5712375/is-it-possible-to-have-optional-permissions-in-android). But still I couldn't figure out a reason for why it's not working.

Thank you in advance for suggestions and recommendations.

Comment: Can you put it directly at your App code ?

Answer (score 5):

First of all, let’s connect a phone on your computer and let’s see how many apps are installed:

```
>> ./adb shell pm list packages
```

You will get a list of package names:

```
[...]
com.google.android.GoogleCamera
[...]
```

Now we are going to get the list of all the permissions:

```
>> ./adb shell pm list permissions -d -g

[...]
group:android.permission-group.CAMERA
  permission:android.permission.CAMERA
[...]
```

And here how to revoke the permission:

```
>> ./adb shell pm revoke com.google.android.GoogleCamera  android.permission.CAMERA
```

and here how to grant it back:

```
>> ./adb shell pm grant com.google.android.GoogleCamera android.permission.CAMERA
```

Comment: and what do we do for Fixed Permission for system apps

Answer (score 1):

```
adb shell pm [grant|revoke] [package] android.permission.CAMERA
```

use adb shell command \

Refer this for further clarification [grant/revoke permission with adb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37675774/grant-revoke-permission-with-adb)